# AS3:loading XML is not working after exporting the air file?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

names();

function names()
{

var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://artbeatmedia.net/application/xmlkpisname.php?username=adel_artbeat&password=ADL1530");
url.contentType = "text/xml";
url.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(url);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);

}
function onLoadComplete(event:Event):void
{
trace('good');
}
```

i used adobe air to load xml using as3,this code works only in the .fla file,but when i export the .air file it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you including the XML file when you publish the AiR app? Happened to me once, forgot to include the file in the publish dialogue....an hour of my life I'll never get back.

Answer (score 0):

if you export a program, trace messages won't be visible.
you can still use MonsterDebugger, but thats a security hazard.

Answer (score 0):

Vizzy tracer will still capture trace calls from an Air app. [Get Vizzy from Google code](http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/)

I tried your code with no modifications just now and it worked just fine, so I suppose your problem is just a failed trace out. Have a go, Vizzy shows even traces from within Flash IDE, so see what happens. If it still fails, then it might be some connection/permission issue.